# button does not respond in Webview

Tags: android, jsp, web

Everything in the android web app is working as expected except the html file input fields coded as `<input type="file" name="filn"/>` in webpage.When i click on the button supposed to load the resources in which the files can be chosen from, it does not respond. Meanwhile in google browser, it works fine. My webview android code is as follows:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    webview =(WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView1);
    webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());     
    webview .getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webview.loadUrl("website"); 
    }
```

What can i do to make it work?

present class which does not work also. I am trying to load a file from html file input in a jsp.

```
public class WebViewActivity extends Activity {
    private String url = "website";
    private ValueCallback<Uri> mUploadMessage;
    private final static int FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE=1;

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
        if(requestCode==FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE)  {
            if (null == mUploadMessage) return;
            Uri result = intent == null || resultCode != RESULT_OK ? null  : intent.getData();
            mUploadMessage.onReceiveValue(result);
            mUploadMessage = null;
        }
    }
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_web_view);
        WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview1);
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());

        webView.setWebChromeClient(
                new WebChromeClient() {
                    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
                    public void openFileChooser(ValueCallback<Uri> uploadMsg) {
                        mUploadMessage = uploadMsg;
                        //Log.d ("myfirstapp_tag", "1) MainActivity.java loaded openFileChooser" );
                        Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                        //Log.d ("myfirstapp_tag", "2) MainActivity.java loaded openFileChooser" );
                        i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
                        //Log.d ("myfirstapp_tag", "3) MainActivity.java loaded openFileChooser" );
                        i.setType("image/*");
                        //Log.d ("myfirstapp_tag", "4) MainActivity.java loaded openFileChooser" );
                        WebViewActivity.this.startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(i,"File Chooser"), FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE);
                        //Log.d ("myfirstapp_tag", "5) MainActivity.java loaded openFileChooser" );
                    }
                }
        );



        webView.loadUrl(url);
        setContentView(webView);
        //android.util.Log.d ("myfirstapp_tag", "MainActivity.java loaded URL and set Content View." );
    }
}
```

Comment: See this :

[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28213890/how-to-detect-div-tag-from-html-file/28214145#28214145][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28213890/how-to-detect-div-tag-from-html-file/28214145#28214145

Answer (score 0):

try this ... may this can help you

taken from [http://androidexample.com/](http://androidexample.com/Open_File_Chooser_With_Camera_Option_In_Webview_File_Option/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=128&aaid=148)

```
     import java.io.File;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.os.Parcelable;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.webkit.ConsoleMessage;
import android.webkit.ValueCallback;
import android.webkit.WebChromeClient;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
 import android.webkit.WebSettings.PluginState;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class ShowWebView extends Activity {

//private Button button;
private WebView webView;
final Activity activity = this;
public Uri imageUri;

private static final int FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE   = 2888;
private ValueCallback<Uri> mUploadMessage;
private Uri mCapturedImageURI = null;


public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.show_web_view);

    //Get webview 
    webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);

    // Define url that will open in webview 
    String webViewUrl = "Your Url Here";



    // Javascript inabled on webview  
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

    // Other webview options
    webView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);

    //webView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);

    //Other webview settings
    webView.setScrollBarStyle(WebView.SCROLLBARS_OUTSIDE_OVERLAY);
    webView.setScrollbarFadingEnabled(false);
    webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    webView.getSettings().setPluginState(PluginState.ON);
    webView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
    webView.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true); 

    //Load url in webview
    webView.loadUrl(webViewUrl);

    // Define Webview manage classes
    startWebView(); 

} 

private void startWebView() {



    // Create new webview Client to show progress dialog
    // Called When opening a url or click on link
    // You can create external class extends with WebViewClient 
    // Taking WebViewClient as inner class

    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {      
        ProgressDialog progressDialog;

        //If you will not use this method url links are open in new brower not in webview
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {              

            // Check if Url contains ExternalLinks string in url 
            // then open url in new browser
            // else all webview links will open in webview browser


                // Stay within this webview and load url
                view.loadUrl(url); 
                return true;


        }



        //Show loader on url load
        public void onLoadResource (WebView view, String url) {

            // if url contains string androidexample
            // Then show progress  Dialog
            if (progressDialog == null && url.contains("any Text If you want") 
                    ) {

                // in standard case YourActivity.this
                progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(ShowWebView.this);
                progressDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
                progressDialog.show();
            }
        }

        // Called when all page resources loaded
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {

            try{
                // Close progressDialog
                if (progressDialog.isShowing()) {
                    progressDialog.dismiss();
                    progressDialog = null;
                }
            }catch(Exception exception){
                exception.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    }); 


    // You can create external class extends with WebChromeClient 
    // Taking WebViewClient as inner class
    // we will define openFileChooser for select file from camera or sdcard

    webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {

        // openFileChooser for Android 3.0+
        public void openFileChooser(ValueCallback<Uri> uploadMsg, String acceptType){  

            // Update message
            mUploadMessage = uploadMsg;

            try{    

                // Create AndroidExampleFolder at sdcard

                File imageStorageDir = new File(
                                       Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
                                       Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES)
                                       , "AndroidExampleFolder");

                if (!imageStorageDir.exists()) {
                    // Create AndroidExampleFolder at sdcard
                    imageStorageDir.mkdirs();
                }

                // Create camera captured image file path and name 
                File file = new File(
                                imageStorageDir + File.separator + "IMG_"
                                + String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis()) 
                                + ".jpg");

                mCapturedImageURI = Uri.fromFile(file); 

                // Camera capture image intent
                final Intent captureIntent = new Intent(
                                              android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

                captureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, mCapturedImageURI);

                Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT); 
                i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
                i.setType("image/*");

                // Create file chooser intent
                Intent chooserIntent = Intent.createChooser(i, "Image Chooser");

                // Set camera intent to file chooser 
                chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS
                                       , new Parcelable[] { captureIntent });

                // On select image call onActivityResult method of activity
                startActivityForResult(chooserIntent, FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE);

              }
             catch(Exception e){
                 Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Exception:"+e, 
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
             }

        }

        // openFileChooser for Android < 3.0
        public void openFileChooser(ValueCallback<Uri> uploadMsg){
            openFileChooser(uploadMsg, "");
        }

        //openFileChooser for other Android versions
        public void openFileChooser(ValueCallback<Uri> uploadMsg, 
                                   String acceptType, 
                                   String capture) {

            openFileChooser(uploadMsg, acceptType);
        }



        // The webPage has 2 filechoosers and will send a 
        // console message informing what action to perform, 
        // taking a photo or updating the file

        public boolean onConsoleMessage(ConsoleMessage cm) {  

            onConsoleMessage(cm.message(), cm.lineNumber(), cm.sourceId());
            return true;
        }

        public void onConsoleMessage(String message, int lineNumber, String sourceID) {
            //Log.d("androidruntime", "Show console messages, Used for debugging: " + message);

        }
    });   // End setWebChromeClient

}



// Return here when file selected from camera or from SDcard

@Override 
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode,  
                                   Intent intent) { 

 if(requestCode==FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE)  
 {  

        if (null == this.mUploadMessage) {
            return;

        }

       Uri result=null;

       try{
            if (resultCode != RESULT_OK) {

                result = null;

            } else {

                // retrieve from the private variable if the intent is null
                result = intent == null ? mCapturedImageURI : intent.getData(); 
            } 
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "activity :"+e,
             Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        mUploadMessage.onReceiveValue(result);
        mUploadMessage = null;

 }

}

// Open previous opened link from history on webview when back button pressed

@Override
// Detect when the back button is pressed
public void onBackPressed() {

    if(webView.canGoBack()) {

        webView.goBack();

    } else {
        // Let the system handle the back button
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}

}
```

Comment: @PaulNgom ... now i edited my answer ... it is a full length web view program ... try it .. you will get almost everything for your activity

Comment: how do i create progressBar1?

Comment: @PaulNgom... add progress bar in your .XML file

Comment: created the progressBar, but still the button does not respond to click.

Comment: to upload files through webview ...check this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12451273/webview-upload-html-not-working)

Comment: i checked the link you provided but i am unable to make the code to run.Can i post the changes i have made? I have a jsp in which i have the html file input.

Comment: @PaulNgom Where you want to intant on button click ?